# Content box not fitting to content properly. Disappears without overflow:auto

Tags: html, css

The content boxes on each of my pages uses the same CSS, however on one page there is a scroll bar in the content box, and the footer does not sit properly.
This is because I use overflow:auto, but when I remove overflow:auto, the content box disappears completely. (The content itself still remains)

I'm not sure what the problem is, since they all use the same CSS and the other pages work fine.

This is the CSS for my content box

```
#contentProducts {
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    width:80%;
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border-radius:20px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px black;
}
```

the content on the page is just 4 boxes with pictures, the css for those is

```
#clothingProduct {
    padding-top:40px;
    position:relative;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:cover;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    height:140px;
    margin-right:12%;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

and this is the CSS for my footer

```
#footer {
    float:left;
    bottom:0;
    position:static;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    color:black;
    margin:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Basically, it should look like this (and does on other pages)
[image: http://i.imgur.com/nwOyWzo.jpg]

but on the product page, it looks like this
[image: http://i.imgur.com/TQYwWNu.png]

I have a workaround fix that involves just setting the height of the box in pixels, but that still doesn't fix the footer sitting in the wrong place.

If you need any more info just let me know, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please give us a fiddle demonstrating your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Md3c/2/

This should give you a general idea of the problem, the footer is supposed to look as it does in the first picture, and without the scroll bar.

Comment: why don't you try `overflow:hidden` instead of `Overflow:auto`

Comment: Hmm something must have changed when I was messing around with it, because when I tried that before, it made the div disappear. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normally when I have a problem along these lines it has to do with a typo/mistake in the HTML. Not closing a tag properly or something along those lines, but it is hard to tell without the relevant HTML.

Comment: Well, that's not cool, but whatever I'll take my lumps. you could try setting "overflow: hidden" on #contentProducts.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, like I said in the title if I don't use overflow:auto/scroll, the whole div just disappears.

Comment: Well something happened while I was changing things and now overflow:hidden works, I don't know what was wrong before but thanks.